# jqgrid addJSONData doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am working on jqGrid, the return json is

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"projectId":"1022","name":"john"}]}
```

then in the function I call

```
 var jsongrid = eval("("+data+")");                  
 var thegrid = jQuery("#projectList")[0];                       
 thegrid.addJSONData(jsongrid);
```

but it give me error: object is null or undefined. don't know why . I didn't use json reader.

BTW, do you know how to use set method to set "total", "page", "records" ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you try to call `addJSONData` method *before* the grid will be created with respect of `jQuery("#projectList").jqGrid({...});`

The usage of `addJSONData` is practically always unneeded (see one from my first posts about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660226/315935)). In the same way you should never use `eval` method which is evil. One uses [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) instead.

I suppose that you should use `datatype: 'json'` to solve your problem. You should post more code to show you how you should use other jqGrid options in your case.

**UPDATED**: From your previous question it seems that you want just send additional data to the server from the form on clicking of the "Search" button. In the case I would suggest to modify the code to the following

```
var $grid = $("#projectList");

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'user595234.json',
    datatype: "json",
    serializeGridData: function (data) {
        return $.param(data) + '&' + $("#project_search_form").serialize();
    },
    jsonReader: {id: "projectId", repeatitems: false},
    colNames: ['ID', 'Name'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'projectId', width: 255},
        {name: 'name', width: 255}
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    pager: '#projectPager',
    sortname: 'projectId',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Simple data manipulation",
    height: "auto"
}).jqGrid("navGrid", "#projectPager", {edit: false, add: false, del: false});

$("#search").click(function () {
    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
});
```

In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user595234.htm) I get just the form from the example of the usage [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and modify it a little. It display the data which you need

[image]

Additionally, like you can easy verify with respect of Fiddler or Firebug, the URL will ba appended with additional parameters like below

```
...?_search=false&nd=1336057299806&rows=10&page=1&sidx=projectId&sord=desc&a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=7&f=8
```

The standard parameters

```
_search=false&nd=1336057299806&rows=10&page=1&sidx=projectId&sord=desc
```

will be appended with parameters from the form

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=7&f=8
```

In some scenarios one can use [jQuery.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) alternatively. It allows to serialize the data in another format (like JSON) or convert the data in some another format (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568113/315935)) which can be easy merged with the standard jqGrid parameters using [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: more detail is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393256/jqgrid-not-display-properly