# jqgrid not working from .change

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following:

```
     function setupGrid(labId) {

       var url = '@Url.Action("GetProgData", "Prog")' + '?lId=' + lId;
       alert(url);

       $("#loginList").jqGrid({
         url: url,
         datatype: "json",
         colNames: ['PNum', 'Client', 'Salesperson', 'Email', ....
       .....
       .....
```

I also have the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
       var labId;

       $("#LabId").change(function () {   // point1
        labId = $("#LabId").val();
        setupGrid(labId); // this goes to setupGrid but DOES NOT go to the given url( url = '@Url.Action("GetProgData", "Prog")' + '?lId=' + lId;)         
       });

       // point 2
       setupGrid(labId);  // this goes to setupGrid  and DOES go to the given url(url = '@Url.Action("GetProgData", "Prog")' + '?lId=' + lId;)
       ......
```

When the program runs the first time, it goes to point2 which then goes to setupGrid function  and goes to the url value in:

```
    url: url
```

When I call it from the .change (point1) it again goes to SetupGrid and the alert shows the correct value but cannot understand why when I put a breakpoint at the url it does not go to the url. Why does it work the first time but when I do it from the .change it does not to go to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that there are common understanding problem how jqGrid works.

If you use `$("#loginList").jqGrid({...});` you need have empty `<table>` element with `id="loginList"`. jqGrid convert the `<table>` element to relatively complex structure of divs, tables etc. So jqGrid *initialize* the grid first of all. It build *outer part* of the grid.

Then jqGrid make Ajax call to `url` (in case of usage `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`) and fill the grid *body*. One can use `$("#loginList").trigger("reloadGrid")` to refresh the grid body.

I hope that it should be clear now that **one can call `$("#loginList").jqGrid({...});` only once**. It you do try to create the grid one more time from existing grid l will be just ignored.

What you should do is just rewriting the code to the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var labId;

    $("#loginList").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetProgData", "Prog")',
        postData: {
            lId: function () {
                return $("#LabId").val();
            }
        },
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['PNum', 'Client', 'Salesperson', 'Email', ....
    });

    $("#LabId").change(function () {   // point1
        $("#loginList").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
});
```

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) more about the usage of methods inside of properties of `postData`. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10408057/315935) you will find alternative way which could be practical in case if it's require to send values from all controls of one form to the controller action.

Comment: @NatePat: One more remark: you have right to vote about 30 questions or answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)), but you don't use the right. Voting is the most important right because **it helps *other people* to find helpful information on the stackoverflow**. So if you want to help other you should use your right and vote up all questions and answers which you find **helpful**.